# MySQL order incorrect with capitalized letters

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to order at table with:

```
select * from my_table order by name
```

but something goes wrong, since:

IT is listed before Ib

For some reason capitalized letters are seen as more important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for case insensitive ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `name` COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci'
```

Comment: Then I get this error:1253 - COLLATION 'latin1_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8

Comment: Ask your database "SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table", look for the column 'name' and change whatever the COLLATE property is to something which ends with "~_ci" (case insensitive).